# Contradictory pandas.DataFrame behavior when assigning value to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df3.head()

2005-02-23       NaN       NaN
2005-02-24  0.888447  2.260956
2005-03-24 -1.616620       NaN
2005-04-12       NaN       NaN
2005-04-28  0.233408 -2.340463
```

If I run the following lines:

```
df4 = df3.dropna(thresh=2).rename(columns={'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'})

df4['c'] = 1
```

the code is executed without warnings. However, If instead I run the following lines :

```
df4 = df3.dropna(thresh=2) #.rename(columns={'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'})

df4['c'] = 1
```

I get the warning message:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

What is going on here?

I can get rid of the warning following its advice by using `loc`:

```
df4 = df3.dropna(thresh=2) #.rename(columns={'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'})

df4.loc[:, 'c'] = 1
```

However, this solution is tricky as is referring to the column `c`
that doesn't exist at the time `loc` is being used.

pandas version: 0.23.4

Comment: Dont know the internal pandas enough to expain, that warning is just want to warn you that `df4['c'] = 1` sometimes will set on copy of df, this always show to me when your df still have #NA in it I think, for this case I think it will still successfully do what you want

Comment: I can't reproduce this with pandas version 0.25.3, no warning here

Answer (score 1):

The warning kinda explains it

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

When assigning with `df[col] = value`, pandas is making a copy under the hood, which I assume can cause memory issues, hence the warning.

However using `loc` you specifying what rows to change so no copy is made, just an update

Read more [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)